# Add custom id to each path created using freedrawing

Tags: fabricjs

I want to know if it is possible to add a custom id to each path created using

canvas.isDrawingMode = true ;

I suppose it should be done if it is possible before the path is created. Is this possible with fabricjs?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the event "path:created" on canvas.

```
canvas.on("path:created", function(opt){
  opt.path.id = fabric.Object.__uid++
});
```

this will ensure you a unique id for every path.

`fabric.Object.__uid` is used to give ids to any element that needs to be referred later (shadows, patterns... )

Comment: Thanks :) Works well!